TS2305: Module '@angular/core/testing' has no exported member async
I updated angular version from 17 to 18 and because of which some modules are no longer supporter especially in spec.ts files while importing them.
Like async from @angular/core/testing and **provideRouterTesting **from @angular/router/testing and **HttpClientTestingModule **from @angular/common/http/testing.
The exact error messages are as follows

@angular/router/testing' has no exported member provideRouterTesting
TS2305: Module '@angular/core/testing' has no exported member async
TS6385: HttpClientTestingModule is deprecated.

I need to know the alternatives for these modules. It will be helpful if anyone can update the alternative modules for these.

Are you using npm instal --force?

The fix for

HttpClientTestingModule is deprecated.

Is to use provideHttpClientTesting
We should also include provideHttpClient

You can try fixing

'@angular/core/testing' has no exported member async

With using waitForAsync

You can try fixing

@angular/router/testing' has no exported member provideRouterTesting

With using RouterTestingModule.withRoutes (Non standalone)
Or
provideRouter and provideLocationMocks combined (Standalone).
Article on Angular Router Testing

Thank you Naren, waitForAsync worked but the remaining two are showing errors while runnning them. I got  Unexpected value 'provideRouter' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation. . If you have any suggestions regarding it.

We should also include provideHttpClient(), along with provideHttpClientTesting(). Then it worked for me.

In some cases, we should also include RouterLink along with provideRouter.
